# How do I extract a list of URLs off a page with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am attempting to extract all urls that https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices has when you click the 'see options' button under each phone and place them into a list of strings.

I am using python with Selenium and wait libraries.
Ive already tried using .text in my parameters. However, I keep running into an error that states:

typeError: 'str' object is not callable
line 17 is the issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome()

class phoneCost:


    driver.get("https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices")

    # extract the names of the phones
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20) #10 second wait
    XPathLocation = """B//*[@id="skip-navigation"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a'"""
    phonePlanLinksRaw = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(By.XPATH(XPathLocation)))
    phonePlanLinks = []


    for element in range(len(phonePlanLinksRaw)):
        link = element
        phonePlanLinks.append(str(link))


    numLink = 1
    for element in range(len(phonePlanLinks)):
        print("phone " + str(numLink) + " : " + phonePlanLinks[element])
        numLink += 1
```

should return a list of urls in string format:

[https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB

,

https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS?sku=190198790569&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%

,

https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XR?sku=190198776631&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB]

Any help is appreciated
Thank you

Comment: link is a webelement... get the href first.  Not too sure if that's your problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic that you should use.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//div[starts-with(@class,'deviceListItem')]/a")))
mblOptions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[starts-with(@class,'deviceListItem')]/a")
mblUrls = []
for mblOption in mblOptions:
    mblUrls.append(mblOption.get_attribute('href'))

print (mblUrls)
```

**output:**

['https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS?sku=190198790569&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XR?sku=190198776631&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_8_Plus?sku=190198454249&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_8?sku=190198450944&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S10+?sku=887276301570&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S10?sku=887276312163&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S10e?sku=887276313870&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_Tab_A_8_LTE?sku=887276299440&planSku=Promo%20Tablet%2015', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_Note9?sku=887276279916&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S9?sku=887276250861&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Motorola/G7_Power?sku=723755134249&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Motorola/Moto_E5_Play?sku=723755125940&planSku=Freedom%20LTE%2B3G%209.5GB%20Promo', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Google/Pixel_3a?sku=842776111326&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Google/Pixel_3?sku=842776109798&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Google/Pixel_3_XL?sku=842776109828&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/ZTE/Z557?sku=885913107448&planSku=Freedom%20500MB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/G7_ThinQ?sku=652810830737&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Huawei/P30_lite?sku=886598061131&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Huawei/Mate_20_Pro?sku=886598058964&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/X_Power_3?sku=652810831130&planSku=Freedom%20LTE%2B3G%209.5GB%20Promo', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/G8_ThinQ?sku=652810832434&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/Q_Stylo_+?sku=652810831222&planSku=Freedom%202GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Alcatel/GoFLIP?sku=889063504010&planSku=Freedom%20500MB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Bring_Your/Own_Device?sku=byod']

Answer (score 1):

Try using list comprehension to achieve the reults. Just take a look at this portion `(By.XPATH(XPathLocation)))` that you used which should be `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "some_xpath")))`.

Rectified one is more like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.get("https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices")
    item_links = [item.get_attribute("href") for item in wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@class,'__DeviceDetailsButton')]")))]
    print(item_links)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all urls that https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices has using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='See Options']")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS_Max?sku=190198786135&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XS?sku=190198790569&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_XR?sku=190198776631&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_8_Plus?sku=190198454249&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Apple/iPhone_8?sku=190198450944&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S10+?sku=887276301570&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S10?sku=887276312163&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S10e?sku=887276313870&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_Tab_A_8_LTE?sku=887276299440&planSku=Promo%20Tablet%2015', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_Note9?sku=887276279916&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%2015GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Samsung/Galaxy_S9?sku=887276250861&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Motorola/G7_Power?sku=723755134249&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Motorola/Moto_E5_Play?sku=723755125940&planSku=Freedom%20LTE%2B3G%209.5GB%20Promo', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Google/Pixel_3a?sku=842776111326&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Google/Pixel_3?sku=842776109798&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Google/Pixel_3_XL?sku=842776109828&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/ZTE/Z557?sku=885913107448&planSku=Freedom%20500MB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/G7_ThinQ?sku=652810830737&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Huawei/P30_lite?sku=886598061131&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%205GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Huawei/Mate_20_Pro?sku=886598058964&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/X_Power_3?sku=652810831130&planSku=Freedom%20LTE%2B3G%209.5GB%20Promo', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/G8_ThinQ?sku=652810832434&planSku=Freedom%20Big%20Gig%20%2B%20Talk%2010GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/LG/Q_Stylo_+?sku=652810831222&planSku=Freedom%202GB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Alcatel/GoFLIP?sku=889063504010&planSku=Freedom%20500MB', 'https://shop.freedommobile.ca/devices/Bring_Your/Own_Device?sku=byod']
  ```